# Can anyone suggest some good links about ASP.net based n-tier architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, wcf, n-tier-architecture

In my Visual Studio solution I m having following types of project:

Class Library - **BusinessLogicLayer**
(I m in doubt how to seperate functionality in BLL)

Class Library - **DataAccessLayer**
(I m in doubt how to seperate functioanlity in DAL)

Class Library - **DataModels**
(Contains various models like User,TimeTable,Address, etc.)

WCF Service App - **To create common WCF service which can be consumed from jQuery(Web App) and WPF App**

ASP.net WebForms Project - **Web Pages**

WPF Project - **Windows application for same** (As it is the requirement)

Setup project - **Septup project to create installer for Windows app**

UnitTest project - **Project to make NUnit basd test cases**

Can u please tell me whether or not I m going right way?
This is my first n-tier based application.

I m actually not clear to seperate functionality in layers even in my very first screen that is login screen.
It could be like this way from code behind file login.aspx.cs in **OnClick_submit** event I should create instance of UserBLL class and then I should call obj.validate(username,password) which returns a model of UserInfo. While that BLL class should itself call UserDB.Validate(username,password)  method which returns model back to PersonBLL class.

If I use this scenario then every operation needs a seperate db conenction.
**I also want to asks whether or not creating applications in this layered approach results in any extra memory consumption.**

Please explain the scenario to me if you are familiar with this.

Comment: Can I write my DAL and BLL using Parallel Programming techniques with Multicore Architectures because sometimes CPU meter shows a problem. One core is running at 100 percent, but all the other cores are idle. Your application is CPU-bound, but you are using only a fraction of the computing power of your multicore system. Is there a way to get better performance?

The answer, in a nutshell, is parallel programming

Comment: See the links [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/three_tier_architecture.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/three_tier_architecture.aspx) [http://imar.spaanjaars.com/476/n-layered-web-applications-with-aspnet-35-part-1-general-introduction](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/476/n-layered-web-applications-with-aspnet-35-part-1-general-introduction) [http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article71.aspx](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article71.aspx) [http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Three-Tier-Architecture.aspx](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Three-

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about others but I find working code to be a far better way of getting a handle on best practices.  Therefore , I'd strongly recommend downloading the Patterns and Practices Data Access drop on [Codeplex](http://dataguidance.codeplex.com/).  It's a little old now but will provide you with a comprehensive reference sample for a Web (albeit MVC), WPF and tiered Services application.

Comment: oh good I will try to explore this Pattern and Practise guide too. I think these types of Lib like enterprise library 5 creates a wrapper for functionalities by adding extra layers .

Comment: Although is was produced by the same P&P team, this is a reference sample rather than a reusable library you can plug into your existing solution.